# Docker swarm use local service instance

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

I try to update a project from a single host to multi host platform.
So basically I want to switch from docker-compose deployment to docker swarm.
My application look like that:
[image: example app]

I have 2 application app1 and app2. app1 create a huge file for app2.
The file is written on a data volume shared between app1 and app2 container.
Previously I use a traefik routing to move from app1 to app2.

So now to do that, I create 3 global services (one for app1, one for app2 and one for traefik). It's working but the traefik can redirect to a different host when you switch from app1 to app2. (The red arrows in the following scheme)

(The traefik rules are like app1.domaine.com --> app1 service)

[image: Topo swarm]

So how I can limit the routing to local host service only ?

Thanks in advance for your help ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to infer the ideal solution here, but I'm not sure `--global` is really your best fit.  Take a look at the documentation for `--mount` (https://github.com/docker/docker/blob/master/docs/reference/commandline/service_create.md#add-bind-mounts-or-volumes).  I am wondering if a named volume shared by the service tasks (containers) might be a slightly better fit than trying to create a global service.  That will create containers for this service on every single host in your cluster.

> So how I can limit the routing to local host service only ?

Why exactly do you want to do this?  Ideally you should be able to load balance between task instances within a service without issue.  If you have to "stick" requests to one container pair, run only one instance of each and use a named volume.

Comment: First thanks for your help @nathanleclaire. The service app1 and app2 already mount a volume (like `--mount type=volume ....` ). Problems come from the size of file I work with ( So it's very long to move file between host.) and second problem, app2 it not stateless. So when a user come in `host X`, all next operation should be done in `host X`. My load balancer assign to a user one server, and allow a migration to another one in case of failure. (But it could be a little bit long). So that why I need to `route` user only inside the current host. That is possible ?

Comment: In my case, I need the requests to be very fast and my swarm is replicated across the world.  When someone reaches a service running on a node in Europe and that service needs to make requests to another service in the swarm, it should *very strongly* prefer the instance of the service that is on the same node and only fall back to the service running on a node in Asia if the local one isn't available.